# order by custom field date in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom field (date) in my Wordpress site, that contain a value like this `June 16,2013`. How can I treat this field as a date and sort? Is there any way to sort posts by custom_field date? Currently it is tested as a string and sorted alphanumerically, not date-wise sorting. I used the following code, but it is not working :

```
<?php   

 $args = array(
  'orderby' => "DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%M %d, %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')",  
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key' =>'release_date'
   );

 query_posts($args);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'orderby' => 'date' yet?

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-and-order-by-date

Comment: But its a custom field and is treated as a string